# Вычисление ресурсоемкости регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, любой-язык

Регулярные выражения довольно ресурсоемки по сравнению с обычными строковыми операциями. Более того, их сложность скрыта за компактным синтаксисом - на глаз, почти невозможно оценить, какой из нескольких возможных вариантов будет быстрее. Проблема осложняется различными диалектами (POSIX, Perl) и реализациями (NFA, DFA) регулярных выражений.

Есть ли возможность/инструмент вычисления количества операций, которые потребуются регулярному выражению для поиска ответа в заданной строке? В первую очередь интересуют PCRE-регулярные выражения?

Comment: думаю, стоит начать с чтения этого http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html#'debug'-mode

Comment: http://regex101.com -> regex debugger.

Comment: А чем-нибудь замерить время не получится?

Comment: @Qwerty, время прямо пропорционально количеству проделанных шагов. Количество шагов, в свою очередь, можно получить с помощью отладчика (@wiktor-stribiżew, к примеру, уже дал ссылку на такой).

Comment: По-моему, вопрос не совсем ясный. Что конкретно надо? Что уже сделано, где проблема? Имеется в виду PCRE или же действительно Perl?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо за замечание, имеется в виду PCRE регулярные выражения. Конкретно хочу сравнить два любых регулярных выражения, например, есть строка "25 октября 2016 года" и два регулярных выражения /\d{4}/ и /^\d{2}.*\d{4}/ - сколько шагов потребуется для поиска в случае каждого регулярного выражения. Нужен алгоритм/инструмент для получения количества шагов, которые потребуется, чтобы найти ответ. Регулярные выражения приведены для примера, они могут быть произвольные. Большое спасибо за комментарии, хотелось бы увидеть развернутый ответ.

Comment: Я тоже пользуюсь сервисом regex101. Сложность зависит от анализируемой строки (очевидно). Математически же это выводить для среднего случая .... бррр. Сложно

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew я не раз видел, как на страницах SO сравнивается два регулярных выражения и предпочтение отдается тому, который берет меньше шагов, что логично и правильно. Хотелось бы понять, как это делается практически. Решение принимается в любом виде: сайт, утилита, алгоритм. Все то, чем вы пользуетесь на практике для решения этой задачи.

Comment: вот здесь хороший ответ и ссылки на статьи с реализациями http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378455/what-is-the-complexity-of-regular-expression

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Единственное надежное средство оценки производительности нескольких регулярных выражений- фактически произвести замер времени поиска и обязательно на различных образцах текста, потому что разные образцы текста будут обработаны за разное время.

Количество шагов которое показывает regex101 имеет смысл (мое субъективное мнение) только при построении рекурсивных регулярных выражений- в них оно позволит более менее оценить эффективность рекурсии.

Сравним три регулярных выражения:

1. `[a-z]` - 33 шага https://regex101.com/r/vC5lG7/1
2. `^[^a-z]*[a-z]` - 4 шага https://regex101.com/r/vC5lG7/2
3. `^[^a-z]*?[a-z]` - 4 шага https://regex101.com/r/vC5lG7/3

Выполним простой замер времени выполнения этих выражений:

```php
function test( $re, $text, $iters ) {
    $t1 = microtime( true );
    for ( $i=0; $i<$iters; $i++ ) {
        $res = preg_match( $re, $text );
    };
    $t2 = microtime( true );
    echo ($t2-$t1)."<br/>";
};

$re1 = "/[a-z]/";
$re2 = "/^[^a-z]*[a-z]/";
$re3 = "/^[^a-z]*?[a-z]/";
$text = "                               a";
$iters = 50000000;

test( $re1, $text, $iters );
test( $re2, $text, $iters );
test( $re3, $text, $iters );
```

Результат:

```
9.5385589599609
9.1712720394135
9.6358540058136
```

Первое регулярное выражение всего на 4% медленнее второго, хотя количество шагов было 33 против 4.
Первое регулярное выражение на 1% быстрее третьего, хотя количество шагов было 33 против 4.

Выводы делайте сами.

---

**P.S.**

> обязательно на различных образцах текста, потому что разные образцы текста будут обработаны за разное время

Кратко поясню.

**Пример**
Дан большой кусок текста где совпадение будет в конце текста. В таком тексте жадная квантификация найдет его быстрее, чем минимальная, но если совпадение будет в начале большого текста, то минимальная квантификация найдет его быстрее.

Answer (score 18):

> Есть ли возможность/инструмент вычисления количества операций, которые потребуются регулярному выражению для поиска ответа в заданной строке?

Посетите  **[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)**.

Введите [`\d{4}`](https://regex101.com/r/tU6tW0/1) в окно регулярного выражения, и увидите:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вычисление заняло 13 шагов, т.е. кол-во операций обращения к функции обратного вызова библиотеки PCRE, скомпилированной при включенном параметре `PCRE_AUTO_CALLOUT`.

Вот [что пишет Люкас Тшещневски](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094007/why-does-using-the-u-and-i-modifiers-cause-one-version-of-a-pattern-to-take-10x):

> The PCRE library supports an auto-callout option through its PCRE_AUTO_CALLOUT flag, which invokes a callback function at every step of matching. I'm 99.99% sure that's how regex101's debugger works. Each callout invocation registers as a step in the debugger.

Чтобы увидеть подробную картину того, что происходит при поиске совпадений в строке с помощью данного регулярного выражения, щелкните **regex debugger**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Производительность регулярного выражения и "кол-во шагов"

Это число не свидетельствует напрямую о скорости разбора выражения конкретной библиотекой регулярных выражений. Просто можно сравнить несколько похожих шаблонов на примере одного и того же текста и сделать выводы относительно их использования.

Для реального тестирования *производительности* регулярного выражения, используйте простой метод:

1) Приготовьте цикл (100-200 тыс. итераций), входные строки, шаблон
 2) Считайте время до начала поиска совпадений до конца
 3) Вычислите среднее время, затраченное на каждую итерацию.

Answer (score 4):

Лучше, мне кажется, помнить что регулярки - это утилита, и существует она не чтобы искать быстро, а искать компактными универсальными шаблонами, не тратя время на разработку алгоритмов анализа.

Если выходит такая ситуация, что скорость работы регулярки критична - то в этот момент надо менять подход к анализу текста на ручной алгоритм. Причина - легче контролировать производительность + прирост производительности.

Если надо парсить специализированные форматы - вроде HTML надо помнить, что для их парсинга есть гораздо более удобные библиотеки, позволяющие сделать парсер читаемее и быстрее.

Comment: А Вы знаете, что очень часто в транслируемых языках регулярные выражения быстрее ручного алгоритма?

Comment: @ReinRaus а как так получается?

Comment: Логично - выполнение ф-ии поиска по регулярке, это скомпилированный код. А он как правило чуток быстрее интерпретируемого. Только из пушки по воробьям бить зачем, зачем нужно шуруповёртом гвозди забивать? Вот назовите мне практический пример, где надо юзать регулярки на большом тексте, да получается так - что они тормозят?

Comment: 1) Было бы интересно посмотреть статистику использования транслируемых и компилируемых языков. Есть подозрение, что на транслируемых языках пишется большая часть кода, ибо это php, js, python, а значит неверно делать антирекомендацию регексам утверждая, что они медленные.

Comment: 2) Я не могу привести такой пример. Понимая как работают регулярные выражения можно составить оптимальное регулярное выражение, которое найдет совпадение сделав минимум откатов. Но, конечно же, если нельзя написать безоткатное регулярное выражение, то применение его к очень большим текстам вызовет падение производительности. К счастью, в большинстве практических реальных задач можно сделать регулярное выражение, которое не будет давать критическое проседание производительности.

Comment: Кроме очень больших текстов есть другая грань вопроса: небольшие тексты. Именно обработка небольших текстов чаще всего используется в программах. И тут регулярные выражения значительно обгонят «чистые» реализации по скорости. Для примера: обгоните `text.replace( /[^a-z0-9а-я]+/i, "" )` чистой реализацией в js. Очень частая задача- санация строки. Заодно сравните разницу в объеме кода и его простоте его понимания.

Comment: На небольших текстах - тормоза словить нереально. Особенно мало волнует JS так как не ест ресурсы драгоценного сервера. Согласен - используется часто, и будет быстрее. Но в посте всё таки я писал про то, что делать при тормозах - там читаемость и контроллируемость парсинга будет приоритетнее. И кстати ещё способ - использовать и регулярки и алгоритм: например бить большой текст на части, а по частям регуляркой идти.

Comment: Да, для больших текстов лучше комплексный подход. А js, это не только клиент... Это еще NodeJS... И, к сожалению, даже его компиляции не спасают «чистые» реализации парсинга.

Comment: Мне кажется,  что автор ответа хотел выразить мысль: регуярки - утилита,  если разобраться как они работают можно и оптимизировать выражение и более того писать свою реализацию под каждый конкретный шаблон. Например поиск подстроки в строке можно сдлеать регулярной, но быстрее каким-нибудь кмп алгоритмом, а если искать несколько строк сразу то Ахо-Корасик... Ни 1 шаблонная библиотека не сможет сдлеать это за вас...

Answer (score -6):

> Регулярные выражения довольно ресурсоемки по сравнению с обычными
>   строковыми операциями

А уж насколько они ресурсоёмки по сравнению с дисковыми операциями, или запросами к БД, или с гонянием данных по сокетам...

Но давайте представим, что:

1. У нас сферический конь в вакууме
2. Задающий вопрос ещё не разучил слово "профайлер"

Как можно оценить "эффективность" того или иного подхода? Очевидно, с определения этой самой эффективности. Классически считается, что либо память, либо скорость.

OK, как можно измерить скорость? Представляете, неожиданно: отметить время до, после, и посчитать разницу! Это настольо банально, что примеров приводить не буду, дабы не оскорблять собеседников.

Как оценить затраты памяти? Вот тут уже сложней, всё зависит от среды исполнения. Поэтому - "*вопрос требует уточнения*" :-)

[P.S.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539105/)

Comment: Если правильно понял вопрос, то там не совсем про ту скорость, что Вы описали в ответе-комментарии (так как он ответом не является), а про "Есть ли возможность/инструмент **вычисления количества операций**, которые потребуются регулярному выражению для поиска ответа в заданной строке?"

Comment: @edem Ну, это какой-то "академический" вопрос тогда получается :) Количество операций просчитывается заранее, по самому регекспу, ну и с учётом входных данных. А вот что это значит, с учётом реализации, и практической эффективности - совсем другой вопрос :-)