# Как эффективнее всего разбить строку на отрезки

Tags: perl

Есть строка и длина отрезка

```
my $string = 'abcdef';
my $cutLength = 3;
```

Нужно получить список строк (`substr` там или `/(?=(.{3}))/g`)

```
@array = ('abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def');
```

ИРЛ в строке `$string` текст размером с томик войны и мира, а длин отрезков `$cutLength` несколько.

Как **эффективно** сделать на перле такие наборы отрезков?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я провёл небольшое исследование и по результатам скажу, что самыми быстрыми подходами к решению задачи являются

```
my @data = $string =~ /(?=(.{$CUT_LENGTH}))/g;
```

и

```
my @array = split //, $string;
my $array_length = scalar @array;
my @data;
for ( 0 .. ($array_length - $CUT_LENGTH) ) {
    push @data, join '', @array[$_ .. ($_ + $cut_length - 1)];
}
```

Работа со строками через перекодировку в `UCS-4le` вне конкуренции по времени, но, к сожалению, скорость нивелируется перекодировкой обратно в utf-8 (для дальнейших нужд).

***Листинг кода***

```html
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use common::sense;
use Time::HiRes qw/gettimeofday tv_interval/;
use HTML::Strip;
use Encode;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Slurp;

##

use constant STR_REPEAT => 1;

##

#testChopReverse(8, 5, 20, 8); say '---';
testArrayJoin1(8, 5, 20, 8); say '---';
testArrayJoin2(8, 5, 20, 8); say '---';
testRegexp2(8, 5, 20, 8);  say '---';
testRegexp1(8, 5, 20, 8);  say '---';
testRegexp3(8, 5, 20, 8);  say '---';
testSubstr2(8, 5, 20, 8); say '---';
testSubstr1(8, 5, 20, 8); say '---';
testSubstr3(8, 5, 20, 8); say '---';

##

sub testSubstr1 {
 my @q = @_;

 my $string = getString( STR_REPEAT );
 my $string_length = length $string;
 foreach my $cut_length (@q) {
  my @data;
  my $tstart = gettimeofday;
  for ( 0 .. ($string_length - $cut_length) ) {
   push @data, substr($string, $_, $cut_length);
  }
  my $time = tv_interval([$tstart]);
  say Dumper ['substr 1', $cut_length, scalar(@data), $time];#, @data[0..3]];
 }
}

sub testSubstr2 {
 my @q = @_;

 foreach my $cut_length (@q) {
  my $string = getString( STR_REPEAT );
  my $string_length = length $string;
  my @data;
  my $tstart = gettimeofday;
  for ( 0 .. ($string_length - $cut_length) ) {
   push @data, substr($string, $_, $cut_length);
  }
  my $time = tv_interval([$tstart]);
  say Dumper ['substr 2', $cut_length, scalar(@data), $time];#, @data[0..3]];
 }
}

sub testSubstr3 {
 # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006875/performance-issue-with-substr-on-a-very-long-utf-8-string
 my @q = @_;

 my $string = getString( STR_REPEAT );
    $string = Encode::encode('UTF-32LE', $string);
 my $string_length = length($string) / 4;
 foreach my $cut_length (@q) {
  my @data;
  my $tstart = gettimeofday;
  for ( 0 .. ($string_length - $cut_length) ) {
#   my $t = Encode::decode('UTF-32LE', substr($string, $_ * 4, $cut_length * 4));
#   my $t = Encode::encode_utf8(Encode::decode('UTF-32LE', substr($string, $_ * 4, $cut_length * 4)));
   my $t = substr($string, $_ * 4, $cut_length * 4);
   push @data, $t;
  }
  my $time = tv_interval([$tstart]);
  say Dumper ['substr 3', $cut_length, scalar(@data), $time];#, @data[0..3]];
 }
}

sub testRegexp1 {
 my @q = @_;

 my $string = getString( STR_REPEAT );
 study $string;
 foreach my $cut_length (@q) {
  my $tstart = gettimeofday;
  my @data = $string =~ /(?=(.{$cut_length}))/g;
  my $time = tv_interval([$tstart]);
  say Dumper ['regexp 1', $cut_length, scalar(@data), $time];#, @data[0..3]];
 }
}

sub testRegexp2 {
 my @q = @_;

 foreach my $cut_length (@q) {
  my $string = getString( STR_REPEAT );
  study $string;
  my $tstart = gettimeofday;
  my @data = $string =~ /(?=(.{$cut_length}))/g;
  my $time = tv_interval([$tstart]);
  say Dumper ['regexp 2', $cut_length, scalar(@data), $time];#, @data[0..3]];
 }
}

sub testRegexp3 {
 my @q = @_;

 my $string = getString( STR_REPEAT );
 study $string;
 foreach my $cut_length (@q) {
  my $tstart = gettimeofday;
  my @data;
  while ($string =~ /(?=(.{$cut_length}))/g) {
   push @data, $1;
  }
  my $time = tv_interval([$tstart]);
  say Dumper ['regexp 3', $cut_length, scalar(@data), $time];#, @data[0..3]];
 }
}

sub testArrayJoin1 {
 my @q = @_;

 my $string = getString( STR_REPEAT );
 my @array = split //, $string;
 my $array_length = scalar @array;
 foreach my $cut_length (@q) {
  my $tstart = gettimeofday;
  my @data;
  for ( 0 .. ($array_length - $cut_length) ) {
   push @data, join '', @array[$_ .. ($_ + $cut_length - 1)];
  }
  my $time = tv_interval([$tstart]);
  say Dumper ['array join 1', $cut_length, scalar(@data), $time];#, @data[0..3]];
 }
}

sub testArrayJoin2 {
 my @q = @_;

 my $string = getString( STR_REPEAT );
 study $string;
 foreach my $cut_length (@q) {
  my $tstart = gettimeofday;
  my @array = split //, $string;
  my @data;
  while (@array) {
   push @data, join '', @array[0 .. ($cut_length - 1)];
   shift @array;
  }
  my $time = tv_interval([$tstart]);
  say Dumper ['array join 2', $cut_length, scalar(@data), $time];#, @data[0..3]];
 }
}

sub testChopReverse {
 my @q = @_;

 foreach my $cut_length (@q) {
  my $string = getString( STR_REPEAT );
  study $string;
  my $tstart = gettimeofday;
  my @data;
  while ($string) {
   push @data, unpack("(A3)", $string);

   $string = reverse $string;
   chop $string;
   $string = reverse $string;
  }
  my $time = tv_interval([$tstart]);
  say Dumper ['chop reverse', $cut_length, scalar(@data), $time, @data[0..3]];
 } 
}

sub getString {
 my $x = shift;
 my $string = read_file( 'Vojna i mir. Tom 1.txt' );
 if ($x && $x > 1) {
  $string = join ' ', map {$string} 1 .. $x;
 }
 unless (Encode::is_utf8($string)) {
  $string = Encode::decode_utf8($string);
 }
 my $hs = HTML::Strip->new(striptags=>[qw/script iframe frame style link/]);
 $string = $hs->parse($string);   
 $hs->eof; undef $hs;
 $string = lc $string;
 $string =~ s/[[:punct:]]/ /g;
 $string =~ s/\n|\r/ /gm;
 $string =~ s/[[:space:]]/ /gm;
 $string =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
 $string =~ s|\s{2,}| |g;
 return $string;
}

#
1;
```

***Тайминги***

```html
$VAR1 = [
      'array join 1',
      8,
      384610,
      '0.260628008132935'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'array join 1',
      5,
      384613,
      '0.193118049865723'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'array join 1',
      20,
      384598,
      '0.478055062683105'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'array join 1',
      8,
      384610,
      '0.258578112854004'
    ];

---
$VAR1 = [
      'array join 2',
      8,
      384617,
      '0.340556945098877'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'array join 2',
      5,
      384617,
      '0.276476087554932'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'array join 2',
      20,
      384617,
      '0.558982025344849'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'array join 2',
      8,
      384617,
      '0.339319053970337'
    ];

---
$VAR1 = [
      'regexp 2',
      8,
      384610,
      '0.198590089614868'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'regexp 2',
      5,
      384613,
      '0.188468908859253'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'regexp 2',
      20,
      384598,
      '0.248025941436768'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'regexp 2',
      8,
      384610,
      '0.197826884658813'
    ];

---
$VAR1 = [
      'regexp 1',
      8,
      384610,
      '0.198430934890747'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'regexp 1',
      5,
      384613,
      '0.183469981155395'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'regexp 1',
      20,
      384598,
      '0.249148044815063'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'regexp 1',
      8,
      384610,
      '0.205187035507202'
    ];

---
$VAR1 = [
      'regexp 3',
      8,
      384610,
      '0.297225016693115'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'regexp 3',
      5,
      384613,
      '0.280919108428955'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'regexp 3',
      20,
      384598,
      '0.32734296295166'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'regexp 3',
      8,
      384610,
      '0.297125981842041'
    ];

---
$VAR1 = [
      'substr 2',
      8,
      384610,
      '9.308260052948'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'substr 2',
      5,
      384613,
      '9.29751593013001'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'substr 2',
      20,
      384598,
      '9.29055691123962'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'substr 2',
      8,
      384610,
      '9.31138106384277'
    ];

---
$VAR1 = [
      'substr 1',
      8,
      384610,
      '9.29793611442566'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'substr 1',
      5,
      384613,
      '43.1393571024628'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'substr 1',
      20,
      384598,
      '40.8735769428101'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'substr 1',
      8,
      384610,
      '46.9814130999603'
    ];

---
$VAR1 = [
      'substr 3',
      8,
      384610,
      '0.116764969924927'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'substr 3',
      5,
      384613,
      '0.120482912780762'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'substr 3',
      20,
      384598,
      '0.125965972229004'
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      'substr 3',
      8,
      384610,
      '0.120614910919189'
    ];
```

Благодарю за соучастие и идеи юзера [@squidepps](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/214032/squidepps)

Comment: Вообще непонятно, при чём тут Encode и HTML. Под нитпрофом прогоните - удивитесь, причём очень.

Answer (score 1):

Пример с `map`, конечно, выглядит "перловей". Но не всегда это оправдано. Возьмём текст побольше да проверим:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use File::Slurp;
use Time::HiRes qw/gettimeofday tv_interval/;
use constant CUT_LENGTH => 4;

my $string = read_file( 'wim.txt' );
my $string_length = length $string;
my @data;

say "String length: $string_length bytes";

my $tstart = gettimeofday;
for( 0 .. ($string_length - CUT_LENGTH) ) {
  push @data, substr($string, $_, CUT_LENGTH);
}

say tv_interval( [$tstart] );
$#data = -1;

$tstart = gettimeofday;
@data = map { substr($string, $_, CUT_LENGTH) } 0..($string_length - CUT_LENGTH);

say tv_interval( [$tstart] );
```

Вывод:

```
String length: 3418597 bytes
1.13446799504089
2.48430399023438
```

Итого, накладные расходы на `map` замедляют процесс аж в два с лишним раза. Это не значит, что `map` - зло :) Просто когда речь идёт об эффективности, самый простой способ ответить на вопрос в каждом конкретном случае - взять да отпрофилировать, хотя бы самым примитивным способом.

Comment: `substr` упомянут в самом вопросе, он - первое, что приходит в голову использовать. но в случае когда есть список длин отрезков при использовании `substr` есть нюансы, см. сколько выполняются `testSubstr1` и `testSubstr2` из моего кода. кроме того `substr` не самый быстрый.

Comment: Ещё раз могу повторить: если слово "профилирование" не знакомо - в морг... Ну это так, не для вас, конечно, а для совсем олигофренов и дураков.

Comment: такого типа ответы я и ожидал. профилирование хорошо тогда когда знаешь что профилировать, т.е. несколько способов решения задачи. посмотри за обсуждение http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006875/performance-issue-with-substr-on-a-very-long-utf-8-string - там топикстартеру предложили способ работы со строкой отличный от substr, примерно такое обсуждение я ожидал тут.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $string    = 'abcdef';
my $cutLength = 4;

my @arr = map { substr($string, $_, $cutLength) } 0..(length ($string) - $cutLength);
print join("\n", @arr);
```