# Regxep Оптимизация поиска тега перед выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, оптимизация

Нужно оптимизировать скорость регулярного выражения, которое должно искать в нижеприведённом тексте от найденной позиции назад и найти предыдущий совпадающий тег. При этом между тегами `{if $var}`, `{else}`, `{/if}` могут быть любые символы. Теги могут быть повторяющимися. Отталкиваться нужно от первого закрывающего тега `{/if}`. Язык программирования PHP.

```
{if $var1}
    {if $var2}
        {if $var3}  
            любой текст
        {else}
            text *(&@$@!/\#<?>~`.,+-_  
        {/if}
    {/if}
       {if $var4}
          any symbols
       {elseif $var5}
          text
       {else}        
          {if $var6}{/if}
       {/if}
    {if $var7}{/if}
{else}
    text and symbols *(&@$$@!
{/if}
```

В данном примере предыдущий тег будет `{if $var3}`

Для поиска `{if $var}` используется:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?(?=\/.?)|({if \$var3}).*?)*(?={\/if})/msi', $replacement, $string);
```

[Ссылка на пример regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aY1yI4/1)

Comment: На каком языке программирования пишете и обязательно ли использовать регулярки?

Comment: @КонстантинПавлович, ответ оформляйте ответом, а не редактированием вопроса.

Comment: А может, просто вот так [`'~({[^}]*})\s*[^{}]*\s*{/if}~'`](https://regex101.com/r/aY1yI4/2)?

Comment: `(({if \$var})[^}]*})\s*[^{}]*\s*{/if}` - если искать в начале текста, то шагов меньше, но в середине текста выдает 2450 steps в сравнении с `(?(?=\/.?)|({if \$var}).*?)*(?={\/if})` который выдал 1531 steps [ссылка на пример сравнения] (https://regex101.com/r/aY1yI4/3)

Comment: Не стоит такие вещи реализовывать через регулярные выражения. Вместо этого стоит один раз пройти по шаблону и построить для него AST, c которым уже работать далее. Это намного эффективнее и гибче любых трюков с регулярками, которые вы сможете провернуть.

Comment: Тогда [`{if \$[^{}]+}\s*(?={\/if})`](https://regex101.com/r/fS4dC8/1) :) Всё, я вне игры. Тут нужен парсер.

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Вы хотите искать «назад»- это уже не правильно. Опишите что конкретно хотите найти в тексте.

Comment: Сделайте реальные замеры скорости работы. Не смотрите на число шагов на регекс101— оно абсолютно не отражает реальную скорость работы. Читайте это:  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538744/Вычисление-ресурсоемкости-регулярного-выражения/539885#539885 . Скорее всего регулярное выражение, которое предложил @WiktorStribiżew более производительно за счёт отсутствия позиционных проверок. Измеряйте реальную скорость, а не шаги.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew если Вам не трудно- сделайте простой тест производительности и опубликуйте Ваше регулярное выражение как ответ. Скорее всего Ваше работает быстрее.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew только сразу скажу, что в нём ошибка, оно должно быть таким: `/(\{[^}]*\}).*?\{\/if\}/s`

Comment: В моем регулярном выражении нет "ошибки", т.к. оно валидное и находит искомый текст. Да, можно и так - [`({if \$[^{}]+})\s*{\/if}`](https://regex101.com/r/fS4dC8/2). Я не отвечаю на вопросы, которые неясны. Вопрос менялся постоянно. Кстати, при анализе текстов с разметкой, использовать `.*` / `.*?` рискованно.

Answer (score 4):

```
preg_match('/{if(?(?={\/?if)|.)*(?={\/if})/', $txt, $matches);
var_dump($matches); // Результат [0]=> string(10) "{if $var3}"
```

Конструкция `(?(?={\/?if)|.)` переводится как найти любые символы, только что бы они не оказались `{if}` или `{/if}`.

[Пример на regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wU0yB5/1)

Comment: Я только понять не могу, зачем использовать `print var_dump()`? Без `print` же все работает...

Comment: @VenZell с перловой аналогичной функцией перепутал. поправил

Comment: @ReinRaus А ответ писался на другой вопрос, где рекурсия была не нужна т.к. искался один, самый глубокий тег. ТС кардинально изменил текст вопроса после написанного ответа, использовав в новом тексте элементы моего ответа.

Comment: Да, извините, в вопросе много дополнительной информации содержится в комментариях, поэтому сначала не правильно его воспринял.