# Скорость обработки: просмотр назад/вперед или именованные группы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Например надо выделить номера из строки вида:

```
*123* *456*
```

Вариант 1 с просмотром:

```
(?<=\*)([0-9]+)(?=\*)
```

Вариант 2 с группой:

```
(\*)(?<TAG>[0-9]+)(\*)
```

и затем извлечь содержимое группы TAG

Что оптимальней с точки зрения скорости выполнения?

Comment: Если у вас числа строго между звездочками, оптимальнее будет использовать поиск и выделение подстроки, а не regexp.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/K5ASxp

Comment: Ну это просто простой пример. Сами конструкции будут гораздо сложнее. Сейчас важно понять на что лучше заложиться с точки зрения общего подхода. В целом задача стоит в "вырезании" произвольной части текста при обработке большого количества строк.

Comment: однако если верить AGS17 и его примеру на dotnetfiddle.net, то разницы фактически нет даже на большом количестве итераций

Comment: Ну regex101.com говорит, что второй вариант быстрее. А если еще вокруг звездочек убрать скобки (нам же их выделять не надо) то еще быстрее. А если еще и `[0-9]++` использовать - то в каких то случаях может оказаться значительно быстрее из за отключения механизма возвратов сверхжадным захватом (правда на данном примере разницы regex101 не показывает, видимо потому, что звездочка после и так достаточно прозрачно намекает, что она не цифра)

Comment: А вообще еще сильно от движка регулярок зависит. одни и те же вещи разные движки внутри исполняют совершенно по разному. а движок или хотя бы в каком языке вы их используете (в большинстве языков движок только один) вы не указали

Comment: Mike, для оценки скорости используете количество итераций в отладчике regex101.com? А я тут как дурак меряю скорость путем написания примеров в своем компиляторе :) Спасибо за идею. Движок у меня QRegularExpression, который в свою очередь использует pcre2

Comment: @nrw Да, там даже в отладчик заходить не надо. справа он сразу пишет столько то matches за столько то шагов

Comment: Кол-во шагов на regex101.com свидетельствует об эффективности регулярного выражения только косвенно. Реальные тесты производительности надо проводить именно в конечной среде. См. [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538744/). Эти 2 выражения неравноценны, нельзя их сравнивать только по производительности. Вариант блоками просмотра вперёд/назад находит накладывающиеся друг на друга совпадения, версия с захватывающими группами — нет. Конечно версия №1 будет выполнятся медленнее, зато найдёт больше совпадений.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, не могли бы вы привести пример, где эти две регулярки дадут разный результат? Я, к сожалению, пока практически не имею опыта работы с ними.